# 7-Zip command-line switch

Tags: 7zip

Is there a 7-Zip command-line switch that prevents the filenames from echoing to the screen as they are added to the archive?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superuser ?

Answer (score 6):

Not built in, but if you add

```
<7z command here> 2>&1 NUL
```

to the end of your command-line, it will redirect all the output into the null device and stops it echoing to the screen. This is the MS-DOS equivalent of

```
2>&1 /dev/null
```

in Linux and Unix systems.

Answer (score 2):

7-Zip has no switch for this. If you are using PowerShell to call 7-Zip, you can redirect the output to null using `Out-Null`. For example,

```
C:\PS>my-create-7zip-function | out-null
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have one, you can still redirect the output using `>` into a file, then deleting the file afterwards. If you are on *nix, you can redirect into `/dev/null`.

### Edit

In MS-DOS and `cmd.exe` you can redirect into NUL, instead of a file. Thanks to [agnul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6069/agnul) for this hint.

Comment: On windows systems you can redirect to NUL (works in cmd.exe, doesn't in powershell).

Comment: in powershell you can pipe to out-null

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is not a switch for that, but you could hide the output redirecting it to a file, for example (DOS batch):

```
7z.exe ... normal parameters > DumpFile.txt
```

This way all the output ends in DumpFile.txt and not on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid file names echoing on the screen and display only the confirmations, do:

```
...\right_path\7z a output.zip folder_to_be_compressed | findstr /b /r /c:"\<Everything is Ok" /c:"\<Scanning" /c:"\<Creating archive"
```